# Missing icons in documentation template generated by phpDocumentor

Tags: documentation, phpdoc

Icons are missing in my generated documentation. They show up as character codes. See the image:

[image: screenshot of the documentation page]

This is a Symfony 4 application. I used a downloaded PHAR file from [phpdocumentor](https://phpdoc.org/), placed it in `my_project_dir/vendor/phpdocumentor/` and ran this from there:

```
$ php phpDocumentor.phar -d ../../src/ -t ../../docs/
```

Then I opened the generated index.html file at `my_project_dir/docs/`. And that's how it looks.

I've checked the path to the assets. It points to the `css/` directory. It's all there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid. It was simple: simply serve the docs through the web server, not just open the index file. So I created a new virtual host and served it at `docs.devdungeon.org`. Very nice. Icons are now showing up.